# How to execute -fs in hadoop pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I want to get the output files from the hdfs to my local storage so i ran this code in my pig script

`Fs -get user/miner/adhoc/results/mine1.txt /home/miner/jeweler/results`

Unfortunately the executing the code returns `error 2997: encountered ioexception`

I also saw `default bootup file /var/lib/hadoop-yarn/.pigbootup not found`

Do i need to import something or do i need to set certain properties in my pig script?

Comment: do u have hadoop client installed in your machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your path is incorrect which gives IOException. Root slash is missing in your path. Correct path: /user/miner/adhoc/results/mine1.txt

You can try this also:

```
fs -copyToLocal /user/miner/adhoc/results/mine1.txt /home/miner/jeweler/results
```

Comment: Hi @Ashish.. I followede your suggestion but i still get the same type of error